# What parts make up a cctv installation at home?

Tags: hard-disk, home-security, ip-camera, poe, nvr

I've scoured the internet and understand the following for cctv installation at home.

```
1. IP Camera(s) (Bullet or Dome)
2. POE Switch to power the IP Camera(s)
```

Now I'm undecided on the following

Manufactures recommend using NVR (Network Video Recorder) to see and record the network feed.

My question is the following

If I connect the POE switch to my windows 10 machine and use a security software like blue iris does it not replace the NVR?

P.S I need a monitor, mouse, HDD in both cases. Using POE switch I save on electrical wiring too.

Please help understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the NVR.

It’s a dedicated piece of equipment that will consume less energy than a windows 10 computer.  NVR’s also contain different hard drives that are specifically made for constant writing and over-writing of video (they last longer).

In my house the NVR is tucked away (and cleverly disguised) on a closet shelf.  This adds to security as an intruder likely wouldn’t be able to find it.  (They steal it and you lost your video of the event.)  (Remember if you choose to hide yours that it does need proper ventilation and should not be in an unconditioned space like an attic.)

We did need to attach a keyboard, monitor, and mouse to the NVR briefly during initial setup.  We set the password and configured the network settings.  Once that is done we shut the system down and removed the keyboard, monitor, and mouse.  Then powered it back up without.   This configuration is called “headless”, and the unit has been in use for years without monitor, keyboard or mouse.   Any of our windows computers can be used anytime to view and download video, and the computers don’t need to be turned on all the time.